# mongodb shown a SYNTAX ERROR in import command

Tags: node.js, mongodb

When running the following command

```
mongoimport --db data_res --collection restaurants --drop --file primer-dataset.json
```

I get the following exception

```
2015-09-30T00:24:51.285+0530 E QUERY    SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
```

Comment: Not really enough to go off of here.  I might suggest offering a snippet of code and more explanation as to the process.

Answer (score 0):

You are ok syntactically. I suggest you to first varify that `mongod` is running or not. If it is not running then start it.

`mongoimport` is used from `terminal`, NOT within the `mongo` shell. Before run this command in terminal you first move to `mongo/bin` directory.

You can also import data by < operator.

`mongoimport --db product --collection product --drop < product.json`